# In Java, how come I can get away with not handling some kinds of exceptions but not others?

Tags: java, exception

How come I can have

```
public void someMethod() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

but not

```
public void someMethod() {
    throw new throw new IOException();
}
```

The first is fine, the second generates the compile error "unhandled exception type IOException".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All things that can be thrown are [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). There are two types of `Throwable`:

- [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)
- [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

One subclass of `Exception` is [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), which is "unchecked" - meaning you don't have to declare or catch them. These are generally for "programming errors", like [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) or [`ArrayOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayOutOfBoundsException.html).

`Errors` are also "unchecked" and are for "unrecoverable" situations, such as `OutOfMemoryError` etc.

Any Throwable *not* a subclass of `Error` or `RuntimeException` is "checked" and must be declared as thrown or caught.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of exceptions in java; `checked` and `unchecked`.

You *have* to catch or specify that your method throws `checked` exceptions. That's the case in your second example with `IOException`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Answer (score 1):

Because `RuntimeException`s and its subclasses are "unchecked" exceptions and do not need to be declared thrown, or caught. Checked exceptions do.

[JLS 11, Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html) covers exceptions in exhaustive detail, [JLS 11.2, Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#11.2) discusses the differences at a high level.

Answer (score 1):

IOException is a checked exception while UnsupportedOperationException is a RuntimeException (unchecked). Checked exceptions must be caught or rethrown.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to look at the difference between check and unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

`UnsupportedOperationException` is a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) which is a type of unchecked exception.  These are exceptions that arise during the execution of a program and indicate a state that is unlikely to be recovered from.

Checked exceptions, the type you must handle in some way, are exceptions that you can probably write code to handle gracefully.

The Java Language Specification, [section 11.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#11.2.5), states it very well:

> The runtime exception classes (RuntimeException and its subclasses)
>   are exempted from compile-time checking because, in the judgment of
>   the designers of the Java programming language, having to declare such
>   exceptions would not aid significantly in establishing the correctness
>   of programs.

There are some good explanations of the idea behind the two types.  The Java Tutorial has a page titled [Unchecked Exceptions — The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), and if you want a more lengthy discussion see [Checked or Unchecked Exceptions?](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

IOException is a "checked" Exception and must be handled.